# Show that $\xi^3\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{\lambda^4}$ in $\Bbb Z [\omega]$

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

We have $\lambda=1-\omega$ where $\omega=e^{i 2\pi/3}$ and $\xi$ an [Eisenstein integer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer). Given that $\xi \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{\lambda}$, how can I prove that $$\xi^3\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{\lambda^4}$$ 
I have thought of writing $$\xi^3 \mp 1 =(\xi\mp 1)(\xi \mp \omega)(\xi \mp \omega^2)$$ and then trying to show that the RHS is divisible by $\lambda^4$ by substituting $\xi=\pm 1 + \alpha \lambda$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ but that gets quite hairy and I can't get anything from it. Is there some easier way? Does the proposition even hold?

Comment: Where are you working? I mean, $\;\xi\equiv\pm1\pmod\lambda\;$ in what ring? Maybe $\;\Bbb Z[\omega]\;$ or you're working somewhere else?

Comment: @Joanpemo yes in $\Bbb Z[\omega]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by a direct computation.
I’ll suppose $\xi\equiv1\pmod\lambda$, and leave the other case to you. We have $\xi=1+\lambda z$ for a $z\in\Bbb Z[\omega]$, and we look at $(1+\lambda z)^3=1+3\lambda z+3\lambda^2z^2+\lambda^3z^3$, modulo $\lambda^4$. There’s  nothing to prove if $z\equiv0\pmod\lambda$, so we can take $z^2\equiv1\pmod\lambda$:
\begin{align}
1+3\lambda z+3\lambda^2z^2+\lambda^3z^3&\equiv1+3\lambda z+\lambda^3z^3\\
&=1+\lambda z[3+\lambda^2z^2]\\
&=1+\lambda z[3-3\omega z^2]=1+3\lambda z[1-\omega z^2]\\
&\equiv1+3\lambda z[1-\omega]=1+3\lambda^2z\equiv1\,,
\end{align}
all congruences here being modulo $\lambda^4$. I used the relation $z^2\equiv1\pmod\lambda$ in the next-last congruence.

Comment: Thank you! $3\lambda^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{\lambda^4}$ because $3\lambda^2/\lambda^4 = -9\omega/9\omega^2 = -\omega^{-1} = -\omega^2$, right?

Comment: Yes, sure: one of many ways of seeing that.